# Parse error: syntax error, the form is not displayed

Tags: php

here is my code
it gives me an error in the last line
the code is not displaying any form or input
i have tried  every thing
plus i am new to programming

```
<?php


 if($connect=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','sy_gov')){

 $sql="SELECT * FROM threads WHERE id='$id'";
 $query=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_object($query)){

?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['$PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php  echo $row->id;?>">
<input type="text" name="topic" value="<?php echo $row->topic;?>">
<input type="submit" value="refresh">
</form>


<?
}

 $sql2="UPDATE threads SET topic='$topic' WHERE id='$id'";
 $query2=mysqli_query($connect,$sql2);
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo "the data are modified";
  }


else{

echo "something wrong";

}
}
?>
```

The PHP code keeps producing an error.
the problem is not in `<?php`  thanx for help

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\g\admin\tut\edit.php on line 35 "please help :("

Answer (score 2):

At first glance it appears that you are missing the character `>` on the end of the following line:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['$PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post"
```

This should probably read:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['$PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
```

Comment: still i have Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\g\admin\tut\edit.php on line 35

Answer (score 2):

```
.....
.....
<input type="submit" value="refresh">
</form>


<?php  -> Here you need to put `php`
}
....
...
```

Comment: no just make it worst        Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\g\admin\tut\edit.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined variable: topic in C:\xampp\htdocs\g\admin\tut\edit.php on line 22

Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\g\admin\tut\edit.php on line 22
something wrong